# What are the differences between limited accounts and computer administrators in XP?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, non-admin

I'm looking for **particular examples of what can and can't be done by a limited account rather than vague generalisations**. For example, run batch files/scripts but what commands can't be used? What areas of the registry can be touched (if any)? What directories are off-limits by default (if any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See these articles from Microsoft:

- [Limited User accounts can protect your Windows XP computer when you browse the Web](http://www.microsoft.com/protect/computer/advanced/useraccount.mspx).
- [Types of user accounts](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ua_c_account_types.mspx?mfr=true).

In terms of the file system, generally speaking, limited accounts can't write to most locations outside of their profile folder.  e.g. the Windows folder and Program Files are off-limits.

In terms of the registry, generally speaking, limited accounts can't modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, only HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Answer (score 2):

**Not that many;**

A limited account cannot touch anything that affects other users on the computer.
This means no access to c:\windows, no access to other user directories, no systemwide settings changes (though any per-user settings are good-to-go)

Limited accounts also can't install some programs (specifically ones that must integrate with the system to function - again going back to the affecting others point), but most of the time can install to their own directory without issue (Fun Fact: Google Chrome installs to a local dir, so limited users can install it without even a single extra step)

As for batch files, likely 99% of commands can be used, but what they can do is limited, again to a local view.

Of course, there will be some things limited accounts can do to affect others, but in general they shouldn't be - and neither can anything hidden inside them, like Virus.exe :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's group those common non-administrator user accounts.

- Power Users
- Users
- Guests

Nothing beats what Microsoft site says. See it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_default_settings.mspx?mfr=true).

For more details of guest account, check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300489) out.